# Show / Hide DIV content block using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Below is complete code I am using to show / hide div block on my page. Currently when I click on particular text heading, it is showing block content of that heading. Then when I click on another text heading, it is showing another block content of that heading but doesn't close previously opened block. I want to close opened block whenever I click on another heading. Please help me.

```
function viewdetail(divno)
{       
    if(document.getElementById("div_com"+ divno).style.display=="block")
    {
        document.getElementById("div_com"+ divno).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("a_title"+ divno).title="Click to view details";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("div_com"+ divno).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("a_title"+ divno).title="Click to hide details";
    }   
    return true;
}


<table>
<?php 
$int_cnt=1;
while(!$rs_list->eof())
{
?>
    <tr> 
        <td>
        <a name="a<?php print($int_cnt)?>"></a>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#a<?php print($int_cnt)?>" id="a_title<?php print($int_cnt)?>" onClick="return viewdetail(<?php print($int_cnt)?>);"><?php print($rs_list->fields("title"));?></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div align="justify" id="div_com<?php print($int_cnt)?>" style="display:none"><table><tr><td>Text will display here</td></tr></table></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
$rs_list->movenext();
$int_cnt=$int_cnt+1;        
}       
?>
</table>
```

Comment: you need to hide all other divs when you show the one you click ?

Comment: just hide them all every time, and after that show the specific one

Comment: You should use jQuery, its good for this kind of stuff. In javascript, you have to do as Deepanshu said..

Comment: fiddle should be given for such missions!!

Comment: are you interested in learning the wonderful thing that jQuery can do for you in these situations? also what is up with all the nested tables? tables shouldn't really be used for styling/positioning of elements, learn to use `<div>` + CSS to create any type of layout

Comment: Deepanshu, Yes I want to do what you are saying. Is that possible by making necessary changes in my current script? Please reply.

Comment: Anyone suggesting a jQuery answer can count on a downvote from me. This is a simple question that does not require thousands of line of external code to solve.

Comment: @KRA if you want a good answer - please post a version of the HTML result of that PHP. It would make the question a lot clearer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Note:** use jquery give class attribute to your div which is same for all the div and make them hide using css.
HTML(example):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="myLink" id="1">this is 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div align="justify" id="div_dom1" class="myClass">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Text will display here for 1</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="myLink" id="2">this is 2</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div align="justify" id="div_dom2" class="myClass">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Text will display here for 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="myLink" id="3">this is 3</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div align="justify" id="div_dom3" class="myClass">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Text will display here for 3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.myClass{
    display:none
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myLink").on('click',function(){
        $(".myClass").hide();
        var divno =  $(this).attr('id');
        $("#div_dom" + divno).show();
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aeNKV/)

Comment: Can you please provide link of sample code where I can read this?

Comment: Hello, it's working fine in demo link but not on my page. Can you please tell me if I need to include any external js or jquery file. Thank you,

Comment: make sure that your a tag attribute id is replaced from id="a_title1" to id="1" and add one more attribute i.e class="myLink"

Comment: I am stuck that why people are down voted the answer though its working correct.

Comment: @Dh... Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question and more specifically http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try using a class to track which div is currently open, and then use that class to find the previously opened div and close it.

Javascript has support in modern browsers for `getElementByClassName` as you can see at http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName.

So maybe rewrite the function as:

```
function viewdetail(divno)
{      
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("last-opened"))
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("last-opened").style.display="none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("last-opened").title="Click to view details";

    }
    if(document.getElementById("div_com"+ divno).style.display=="block")
    {
        document.getElementById("div_com"+ divno).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("a_title"+ divno).title="Click to view details";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("div_com"+ divno).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("a_title"+ divno).title="Click to hide details";
        document.getElementById("a_title"+ divno).className = "last-opened";
        // Or this next line if you want to keep previous classes there.
        // document.getElementById("a_title"+ divno).className = document.getElementById("a_title"+ divno).className + "last-opened";
    }   
    return true;
}
```

I didn't test it, but I think that would work.

Answer (score -1):

The logic in you function only handles the last clicked div. Therefore you need to 
A, do as others have sugested and close all
B, store the divno in a variable so you know witch one was previously opened and should now be closed
C, use JQuery